# React Native 0.66 - Cant open React-Native-Debugger, Flipper is default

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger, flipper

I've upgraded to React Native 0.66.
I can open the developer menu but its seems the now flipper is the default choice.
I got only "Open Debugger" - which open Flipper.
I had a "Debug" option that no longer there.

I have issues with Flipper that I could not resolve -
How can I use react-native-debugger?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems that Hermes was enabled in my Podfile - once I upgraded to 0.66 it force the use of flipper

Doing `hermes_enabled => false` in Podfile and running `pod install`  enable to work with react-native-debugger again:

```
use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"], :hermes_enabled => false)
```

Comment: Don't forget to `cd ios` and `pod install` after making this change.  Worked great!  So sad that RND does not [yet support hermes](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/573)

Answer (score -2):

Need to install Flipper Dev Tool download from [here](https://fbflipper.com/)